# Not able to set scope value on to select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I have written code like below

```
<select ng-model="runnames" 
ng-options="runs.runname for runs in season.runs" 
ng-change="Onchangefunc(runnames)">
```

This works fine. But problem is that, i want to change the selected value of the from another function. I set the value like

```
$scope.runnames = 'A';
```

Here is how JSON looks like

```
[
  {"runid": "1","runame": "A"},
  {"runid": "2","runame": "B"},
  {"runid": "3","runame": "C"}
          ]
```

But select value does not change. Anything wrong i am doing?? or any other feature to use?

Comment: We need to see more code. Like, what's inside `seasons.runs`. If `abc` is not inside that, it's not going to work like that.

Comment: @Antonio Laguna  - Added json for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-options  works on Object basis.

Its us the **key** which is used in **track by** for setting or making option selected.

I have Modified the HTML as follows for my own purpsose.

```
<select ng-model="runnames" 
ng-options="runs as runs.runame for runs in season track by runs.runid" 
ng-change="Onchangefunc(runnames)">{{runs}}
</select>
```

AND JS

```
controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.season = [
  {"runid": "1","runame": "A"},
  {"runid": "2","runame": "B"},
  {"runid": "3","runame": "C"}
          ] 

  $scope.runnames = {"runid": "3"}

})
```

Use the  **track by** in your **ng-options** and set that value in your external function.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NcjMIchXGNVvOswglYZE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example provided near the top of this page, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions, you may need to ensure your  $scope.runnames variable contains a definition for 'name'. i.e.

```
$scope.runnames = { name: 'abc' };
```

Comment: Is 'abc' even a valid choice in the context of your options?

Comment: That was just a sample. I have modified my code now.